# Any idea on how i can scrape a website one level deep then translate the pages using Google translate say from(English to French)

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-translate

So essentially what i need to do is to scrape a website one level deep(ie the current website and every link on the page) store them in a folder,then translate using Google translate

I tried using Httrack but ran into some errors such as 403 forbidden but major what i would really like know is how to translate the web pages using Google translate